# EXCEL VBA Multiple range with exceptional column

Tags: excel, vba

I use `Selection.Row = 1` to `Exit Sub`.

But I need the code to continue if the `Range("B1")` is being used

Any idea how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you should avoid `Selection` altogther. But for you question as asked

1. Test if the Selection contains Row 1.
2. If it does, then a second test is run, testing if `B1` is contained in the `Selection`, if yes the code exits, if not the code continues.

It is always best code-wide to break two individual tests that must be met into separate tests with the most common early test exit being tested first. This is more efficient that running an `And` and testing the second condition if the first has already failed.

**code**

```
Sub TestExit()
Dim rng1 As Range
If Not Intersect(Rows(1), Selection) Is Nothing Then
Set rng1 = Intersect(Selection, [b1])
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, may I know why `Selection` is not an ideal choice? I found it is very easy to use somehow.

Comment: What is your full code - perhaps a new question? Select is *normally* not necessary, plus it can lead to errors in coding

Comment: I will post my code in a new question. Will keep you update. Thank you!

Comment: did you forget this question?

Answer (score 0):

`If Selection.row = 1 And Selection.Column <> 2 Then Exit Sub`

Comment: If A1 and B1 are both selected then this fails. And you didn't appear to read my earlier post about avoiding an unneccesary `And`